# how to implement Saved Games on Google Play Games Services v2 SDK?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Google has released a new play Games service v2, but their implementation of saved games is confusing. Developer Guides for implementation of Saved Games for V2 are the same as v1...
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames

But in v2 users automatically get signed in as game launch without any scope request.

Anyone has any idea how to implement correctly v2, there is no example available for v2.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to request the scope.

I tested Saved Games features using google play game services v2 without requesting any scope, because there is no way to request, but everything worked fine.